# Is there other ways to compare bitmaps in Android beside comparing pixels and bytes?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, bitmap

I tried get pixels and converting bitmap to bytes array and i got either bitmaps are equal 100 % or 0 % .. I need to know the percentage of similarity between two bitmaps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170488/android-java-percentage-bitmap-pixel-difference-between-two-images  and  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Percentage_difference_between_images

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a library for this, but you might try creating a heuristic map of the colors and comparing those.

Comment: can u give me a link or a reference witch i can learn how to create heuristic map of the colors from ??
thanx for yor time ..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, you don't say in what kind of differences you want to detect.

There are two well-known similarity metrics: SAD and SSD (sum of absolute differences and sum of squared differences). In order to get a percentage, you can relate these to the maximum achievable from the reference image (by choosing black or saturated values, whatever gives the largest difference).

Example: compare pixel values 45 210 56 and 40 220 60 (8 bits grayscale) using SAD:

```
P = 1 - (|45-40| + |210-220| + |56-60|) / (|45-0| + |210-255| + |56-0|) = 87%
```

Another is the normalized correlation score (the correlation coefficient of linear regression).

Comment: I'm developing an app using signature so I need to compare the signature drawn with another one stored in SD card

Comment: @MohamedFadhl in that case it is not a good idea to compare pixels directly because signature A could have the same pixels as signature B. To compare signatures you will need to extract features and compare against the features not the pixels.

Comment: @Enriqe I'm new in android so can u give me more specific ways or wxamples ?? thanx